# How to get values of form in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Whats wrong with the code. I am getting values from form on jsp using request.getParameter. request.getParameter at line 1,2,3 are successfully fetching the value from form. but i am getting value of period 0 at the end.

```
        int period=0;

   String period_in_years = request.getParameter("tenure");
String period_in_years5 = request.getParameter("tenure5");
    String period_in_years6 = request.getParameter("tenure6");

 /*line1--*/System.out.println("value in string tenure is="+period_in_years);
 /*line2--*/System.out.println("value in string tenure5 is="+period_in_years5);
 /*line3--*/System.out.println("value in string tenure6 is="+period_in_years6);
    if( period_in_years5==null && period_in_years6==null && period_in_years!=null )
    {
        period=0;

         period = Integer.parseInt(period_in_years);
        System.out.print("period1 at jsp="+period);
        period_in_years5="";
        period_in_years6="";

    }else if( period_in_years==null && period_in_years6==null && period_in_years5!=null)
        {
            period=0;
            period = Integer.parseInt(period_in_years5);
            System.out.print("period5 at jsp="+period);
            period_in_years="";
            period_in_years6="";
     }else if(period_in_years==null && period_in_years5==null && period_in_years6!=null)
     {
         period=0; 
         period = Integer.parseInt(period_in_years6);
        System.out.print("period6 at jsp="+period);
        period_in_years="";
        period_in_years5="";

     }
System.out.print("final period in jsp="+period);
```

Comment: Are you expecting only ONE of 
period_in_years, period_in_years5, period_in_years6
to be not-null?
If in any case more than one form entity is not-null, then your conditions will never get executed.
Please rectify conditions accordingly and try.

Comment: No. One should contain value and rest should be null and one which have value should match the if condition

Answer (score 0):

If I'm look correctly, sorry if not, you never runnning in one of your if-blocks. Your variables `period_in_years`, `period_in_years5` and `period_in_years6` aren't null. You setting `period` to 0 at the beginning of your code and didn't change the value ever after. That's why you getting 0 at the end.

Comment: Yes, but what is the solution. where should i change the code?

Comment: That depends on the wanted outcome. What do you expect in your use-case the period at the end should be?

Comment: I am getting like this at line 1,2,3 value in string tenure1 is=3
value in string tenure5 is=
value in string tenure6 is=

Comment: so here the tenure1 contain value and tenure5,6 does not but still at last it shows 0 in period

Comment: Okay. I see. If i'm understanding you correctly. Only the first formelement (tenure) contains a value. The others don't, right?
Then your condition checks aren't correctly explained.

The Methode `request.getParameter("someParameter")` returns an empty String instead of null, for any parameter which can be found on your jsp.
So the statement  `request.getParameter("someParameter") == null` is always false. your condtion check should look like   `period_in_years.equals("")` instead of   `period_in_years == null`

Answer (score 0):

Please apply 
**`period_in_years5.isEmpty()`** check instead of 
`period_in_years5==null` check if the form parameter always exists.

Best way to validate: **`period_in_years5==null || period_in_years5.isEmpty()`**

This is because if your parameters exists, then request.getParameter("param_name") will return empty string instead of `null`.